# Writing a const and non-const variant of a function

Tags: c, function, types, return, constants

I implemented a rather complex functions, but for the sake of a minimal example, let's stick with this:

```
(const) char * my_function((const) char *input) {
  return input;
}
```

The problem arises when I need to call the function one time with a const and once with a non-const value:

```
const char *a = "ABC";
char b[3];

// The following fails without using const in the declaration of my_function
const char *result_a = my_function(a);

// The following fails when using const in the declaration of my_function
char *result_b = my_function(b);
```

Can this problem be solved in plain C without repeating the same function with different names?

---

I know this can be done with a second file or an incredibly long `#define`, but is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

If within the function the string pointed to by the parameter is not being changed then the function definition can look like

```
char * my_function( const char *input ) 
{
    // ...
    return ( char * )input;
}
```

Thus you can write

```
const char *a = "ABC";
char b[3];

const char *result_a = my_function(a);
char *result_b = my_function(b);
```

That is it is the responsibility of the user of the function to process correctly the returned object.

This approach is used in most standard C string functions.

For example

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```